# Limitations of Bluetooth Controller and Stack

Tags: bluetooth, controller, stack

I need your help in selecting Bluetooth controller chip and Open-source Bluetooth Stack for embedded Linux.
Generally what are hardware/Bluetooth controller limitations that should be considered? e.g. Pairing/connecting with multiple Bluetooth headsets, Audio quality. etc.

Generally what are Bluetooth Stack limitations to be considered? e.g. Supported services, Profiles etc.?

Answer (score 1):

In general following parameters needs to be considered at various levels (BT controller, BT stack , Profiles):-

**1. Bluetooth Controller IC**

Bluetooth core 4.0 specifications?
BT Power class? e.g. Class 2 for 10 m range

HCI options? UART, Max baud rate supported?

PCM audio over TDM?

"What audio codec formats are supported over air i.e.
Air codings supported?"

Transparent data support for Air coding?

mSBC codec support?

Programmable PCM audio stream format?

- Sampling Rates supported? 16 KHz, 44.1 KHz etc.
- Sample width supported? 8,16,24,32 bits per Sample
- Sample encoding? Endianness MSB/LSB first
- Number of channels per slot? 1 for mono, 2 for stereo
- PCM Master/Slave configuration?

Forms of Bluetooth wireless technology systems?
Basic Rate (BR), EDR (Enhanced Data Rate), LE (Low energy)?

QDID listed with Bluetooth SIG?

Tuning required for Bluetooth Carrier frequency tolerance, RF radiated field strength, Rx sensitivity?

Wifi/Bluetooth co-existence?

DSP Co-processor for better audio quality?

Evaluation board for early development?
Supported BT stacks? E.g. BlueZ ver 5.x?

How to send updated firmware/binary  files /configurations?

Documentation about Bluetooth Qualification testing?

What are Bluetooth Firmware binary file sizes and time required to load?

**2. Bluetooth Stack**

Open source stack? "BlueZ ver 5.x support?

What extra packages required? E.g. PulseAudio/ALSA, oFono, D-Bus"

HFP 1.6 AG/HF role support?

mSBC codec negotiation support?

eSCO connection/link support?

Transparent data support for Air coding?

EDR support with packet types 2-EV3, 30EV3, 2-EV5, 3-EV5

Features supported 
QoS, 
eSCO, 
Secure Simple Pairing, 
Extended Inquiry Response, 
Codec Negotiation?

Ability to change Bluetooth name?

supported profiles
Basic: GAP, SPP
AG Role: HSP >= 1.1, HFP >= 1.6
Profile server support?

How to start/stop Stack? BT Chip default power when phone boots up?

Stack callbacks handling for Async. events, interface libraries, sample code?

**3. Bluetooth Profiles**

HSP profile which roles? Which version?

HFP profile which roles? 
AG
HF
 - Which versions?

- Which optional features supported?

  - Reject an incoming call?
  - Place a call with phone number supplied?
  - Place a call using memory dialing?
  - Place a call to the last number dialed?
  - Call waiting notification?
  - Calling Line Identification?
  - Echo canceling (EC) and noise reduction (NR)?
  - Ability to transmit DTMF codes?
  - Remote audio volume control (+VGM=#, +VGS=#)
  - Volume level synchronization (AT+VGS=#, AT+VGM=#)
  - Resume and Hold call?
  - Wide Band Speech?
  - Individual Indicator Activation? e.g. for Battery status

Profile Extensions?

Custom/Vendor specific  AT commands support?
e.g. AT command to report battery level indication?